# IDA python list functions through command line script

Tags: python

I have written an IDAPython script which executes and list the functions in a DLL through IDA Pro GUI. But, the same script when executed through command prompt does not list the functions present in a DLL.
Below is the code:

```
from idautils import *
from idaapi import *
import idc
ea = BeginEA()
dll_functions=[]
fp=open(r"C:\Users\xxx\Documents\check\fun_output.txt","w")
fp.write("check")
for funcea in Functions(SegStart(ea), SegEnd(ea)):
    functionName = GetFunctionName(funcea)
    dll_functions.append(functionName)
    fp.write(functionName)
    print(functionName)
idc.Exit(0)
```

It does not list the functions when executed through cmd prompt as:

```
idaq -A -S"C:\Users\XXX\Documents\script\ida_total_fun.py" "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\output\sample.dll"
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the script requires open the IDA DB in order to do get what it is needed.
According to the IDA help:

```
 -S###  Execute a script file when the database is opened.
```

You could either try instead of sending the url dll, just send the IDB file path or try to use the option -c which creates the  database.

```
 -c     disassemble a new file (delete the old database)
```

You can also check here http://www.hexblog.com/?p=128 a very good entry about the topic

And the IDA help,
https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml

Comment: thanks! I tried IDB file, temp database but it didn't work. The solution working for me is to use idaapi.autoWait() method which waits for IDA auto analysis to complete and list the functions